# How do you embed resource files in C?

Tags: c, embed, resource-files

The only way I know how to do this is to convert the file into a C source file with a single byte/char array containing the contents of the resource file in hex.

Is there a better or easier way to do this?

Comment: Hopefully, you'll be aware that the answer to this problem depends **entirely** on the specifics of the toolchain you're using (compiler, linker, executable format, etc.).  So you'd do well to add as much detail as possible to your question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yea, good point.  I'm using the GNU Arm Toolchain (arm-elf-gcc).

Comment: It's worth noting that I was really hoping for a _portable_ answer, so this question will actually be more useful to others who find it.

Comment: The most portable solution is the one you already have.

Comment: Here is a link to a program that says it converts binary files to C/C++ header.  I can't vouch for it though since I haven't used it myself. http://sourceforge.net/projects/bin2header/

Comment: Seems strange to me that such an old low-level language has no way to compile or link binaries along with the source code which will use them.

Comment: There have been hacky, non-portable ways of embedding binary data in source or linker files for decades. There is [a proposal for an `#embed` preprocessor directive](https://thephd.dev/finally-embed-in-c23) to support this in a standardized cross-platform way for C23. Keep your fingers crossed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice trick I use with a gcc-arm cross compiler; including a file through an assembly language file. In this example it's the contents of the file `public_key.pem` I'm including.

**pubkey.s**

```
 .section ".rodata"
 .globl pubkey
 .type pubkey, STT_OBJECT
pubkey:
 .incbin "public_key.pem"
 .byte 0
 .size pubkey, .-pubkey
```

corresponding **pubkey.h**

```
#ifndef PUBKEY_H
#define PUBKEY_H
/*
 * This is a binary blob, the public key in PEM format,
 * brought in by pubkey.s
 */
extern const char pubkey[];

#endif // PUBKEY_H
```

Now the C sources can include `pubkey.h`, compile the `pubkey.s` with gcc and link it into your application, and there you go. `sizeof(pubkey)` also works.

Comment: How does sizeof work? Isn't sizeof evaluated at compile time, where the contents of pubkey.s won't even be considered? EDIT: Did you mean strlen?

Comment: @thenickdude [`.size`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Size.html#Size) is probably doing that trick.

Comment: ok, doesn't work for me, I had to specify the size in a "variable": `pubkey_size:
        .int (. - pubkey)` directly after the `.size`; and of course `.globl pubkey_size` and `.type pubkey_size, STT_OBJECT`. Used via `extern const int pubkey_size;`

Answer (score 2):

The way you've described is the best/easiest/most portable. Just write a quick tool (or find an existing one) to generate the C files for you. And make sure you make correct use of the `const` (and possibly `static`) keywords when you do it or your program will waste large amounts of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this a while ago and I created a tool for this.
It's a python tool called **[mkcres](https://github.com/jahnf/mkcres)** (https://github.com/jahnf/mkcres) and I put it on github.

- Although documentation is lacking a little, there are examples on how to integrate it into a build process with CMake or plain make files.
- Takes a .json file as resource file generation configuration
- It can detect changes on resource files and automatically regenerate
  the corresponding C files if necessary.
- Downside: You'll need python (2 or 3)
- Upside: Not compiler specific, should work with every C/C++ compiler.