# How to embed resources in Rust executable?

Tags: rust

This is the cousin of [this question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036769/how-do-you-embed-resource-files-in-c) asking the same thing for C.

Basically, is there a better way than to just turn it into a giant byte array and putting it in a source file?

Alternatively, does a macro have the ability to do this? (Rust Macros... are a dense looking and their exact capabilities are not known to me.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good way to include external resource data into Rust source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505275/is-there-a-good-way-to-include-external-resource-data-into-rust-source-code)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You probably want [`include_bytes!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_bytes!.html).

If you are in older versions of Rust, use [`include_bin!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/macro.include_bin!.html) instead.

Comment: Perfect. :) I had a feeling a macro would do it, but google didn't come up with anything and I just didn't think to search there :)

Comment: Note that this macro has been renamed to [`include_bytes!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_bytes!.html) in newer Rust versions.

Answer (score 9):

You could alternatively use this tool https://github.com/pyros2097/rust-embed Which was created by me which generates rust code for your resources.

Comment: Would you recommend using this for a 50 MB binary file which I plan to parse with `nom`? Thanks

Comment: Yeah go for it. The only thing that I could see that be a problem is in release mode the macro will generate a Vec<u8> which is going to have 50MB of code generated. I don't know how long rust will take to compile the code and whether the code will get generated properly in the first place since I haven't tested with such a large file.