# How do I make a Rust program which can be executed without using `cargo run`?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How can I make a program in Rust which can be executed from anywhere without using `cargo run`, by just clicking on the file?

Is there any crate? I have written code for snake game and I want to run it by just clicking on a file.

Comment: The executable is created in the `target/release` directory when you run `cargo build --release`. Note that it might not be executable from _anywhere_, but only from machines that use the operating system and hardware compatible with the one you are using; e.g. if you build on PC running Windows, the resulting executable will run on other PCs running Windows. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Also, to expand on the above comment, this executable is automatically self-contained and can be run by clicking on it. No crate needed, and no cargo. It should work everywhere that uses the platform for which you compiled (e.g. Windows) unless you use specific crates with system library dependencies.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you compile a Rust application with:

```
cargo build --release
```

it will place a binary file in `./target/release`. So if your application is called `snake_game`, you can run it with `./target/release/snake_game`, or by double-clicking on that file.

This binary is completely self-contained, so you can move or copy it to somewhere else on your computer.

Comment: As OP mentions a game, I assume there are resources ([How to embed resources in Rust executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27140634/155423)). As OP mentions "click", I assume they are on Windows.

Comment: By this way binary file has been placed but it is not opening! Is it for linux also? I am a linux user.

Comment: I didn't see any real difference between `--release` and debug. The debug build runs just fine. I did see a difference when I turned on dynamic linking in my game library (Bevy), which caused the executable to stop working.

Comment: @jpaugh Are you saying that the binary gets placed in the same directory regardless of if you build with `--release` or `--debug`?

Comment: @PeterHall. No. I'm saying that the program can be run directly, even if you don't use `--release`.

Comment: @jpaugh It's fairly typical for release  builds to run 50x faster than debug builds. You will see the difference when your game gets more complex.

Comment: @PeterHall That's useful info, especially for inexperienced devs who are also new to Rust. However, it's also an unnecessary time suck while I am still actively developing the project at hand.

Answer (score 14):

## First build your binary for release

```
cargo build --release
```

## Next handle permissions

Typically `chmod +x target/release/whateverYourProgramIsCalled` to make executable, but cargo did this for us already

## You can check it's Octal Permissions

```
ls -l target/release/whateverYourProgramIsCalled
chmod +x target/release/whateverYourProgramIsCalled
ls -l target/release/whateverYourProgramIsCalled
```

As you can see nothing has changed... the permissions were already correct for executing

## Run that executable

```
./whateverYourProgramIsCalled
```

## Optional: run from anywhere

You can run that binary anywhere from the command line

To do this you need to add it to your path

For mac you can add to your path from `/etc/paths`

whatever editor you prefer.... vi, code, etc...

```
sudo code /etc/paths
```

I added a path like this, saved and authenticated with a password

```
/Users/`whoami`/code/rust/binaries
```

whoami command is surrounded by `

next copy your new binary over to where it needs to be, in that binaries folder

```
cp whateverYourProgramIsCalled /Users/`whoami`/code/rust/binaries
```

#### Then open a new terminal window

#### Check your command is in your path

```
where whateverYourProgramIsCalled
```

#### Run your command from anywhere

```
whateverYourProgramIsCalled
```

## Rejoice

Comment: Always linux... Help on windows too, please.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add another answer here, not sure if it's related to a more recent version of rust.

If in the root of your project you just run the command `cargo install --path .` it will add it to cargo and allow you to run the binary just with project name.

Answer (score 1):

There is another method you can do by using rustc. It will create an executable binary file in the same directory where your file exists.

Make sure you are in the src directory and the name of your file is main.rs.

```
rustc main.rs
./main
```

The advantage of using rustc is that you can run any file not only main.rs. just do:

```
 rustc filename.rs
 ./filename
```

You can run it from terminal and also by clicking on that file.

Comment: The disadvantage is that you need to download every single dependency manually, and then pass each as an argument to `rustc`. I can't see any advantages to this.

Comment: Also, with `cargo`, you can specify other binary entry points besides `main.rs` in `[bin]` sections of your `Cargo.toml`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cargo install --path .
```

if you want to run it as another cli app installed locally,
idk why people are recommending to start sudo cping sh** around manually...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution has already been suggested by [another answer](/a/73569214/2189130).